# OpenGL: How to do RGBA->RGBA blitting without changing destination alpha

Tags: opengl, alphablending

I have an OpenGL RGBA texture and I blit another RGBA texture onto it using a framebuffer object. The problem is that if I use the usual blend functions with 
`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA),`
the resulting blit causes the destination texture alpha to change, making it slightly transparent for places where alpha previously was 1. I would like the destination surface alpha never to change, but otherwise the effect on RGB values should be exactly like with `GL_SRC_ALPHA` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`. So the blend factor functions should be (As,As,As,0) and (1-As,1-As,1-As,1). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the blend-modes for RGB and alpha to different equations:

```
void glBlendFuncSeparate(
    GLenum srcRGB, 
    GLenum dstRGB, 
    GLenum srcAlpha, 
    GLenum dstAlpha);
```

In your case you want to use the following enums:

```
  glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE);
```

Note that you may have to import the glBlendFuncSeparate function as an extension. It's safe to do so though. The function is around for a very long time. It's part of OpenGL 1.4

Another way to do the same is to disable writing to the alpha-channel using glColorMask:

```
void glColorMask( GLboolean red,
                  GLboolean green,
                  GLboolean blue,
                  GLboolean alpha )
```

It **could** be a lot slower than glBlendFuncSeparate because OpenGL-drivers optimize the most commonly used functions and glColorMask is one of the rarely used OpenGL-functions.

If you're unlucky you may even end up with software-rendering emulation by calling oddball functions :-)

Comment: I've found glColorMask() support to be generally quite decent.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [glColorMask](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/colormask.html)()? It let's you enable/disable writing to each of the four color components.