# OpenGL ES 1.1: How to substitute glBlendFuncSeparate?

Tags: android, opengl-es, fbo

My problem is pretty much the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146140/opengl-how-to-do-rgba-rgba-blitting-without-changing-destination-alpha).

This would also be the answer, if glBlendFuncSeparate was available for me:

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE);
```

However, since I need to provide support for MALI-400MP (Samsung Galaxy Nexus S II), I can't use glBlendFuncSeparate (GL_OES_blend_func_separate extension not present).

use of glColorMask is adviced, but how do I use it properly?
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems pretty well answered in the other question, but if all you want to do is disable writing to the alpha channel, you just call `glColorMask(true,true,true,false);` before drawing your blended objects. This locks the alpha layer from being modified while it is being written.

Comment: Accepted this. My problem was that I hadn't not cleared the FBO as 0,0,0,1 at the beginning, and the alpha values were bit random.